# How to solve a difference equation in terms of initial value $y_0$ and describe the behavior of its solution as $n$ approaches $\infty$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, initial-value-problems

Here's the question: 
[image]

For first equation, the answer should be:

$$y_n = (-1)^n * (.5)^n * (y_0-4) + 4$$
and that $y_n$ goes to $4$ as $n$ approaches $\infty$.

I'm confused on how to get there. If anyone could point me in the right direction to solving these equations that would be much appreciated !!

Comment: Same comment as to your other question: these are two completely standard exercices of direct application of the relevant chapter in your notes.

Comment: (And none of the tags you (randomly?) selected applies.)

Comment: There are no solutions (just answers) in our text and very limited examples. Thanks to people who actually offered help, I understand that I need to plug in a few n values and then construct a general rule for yn. I didn't ask if these were standard "exercices". I can't find solutions to these problems online and I've tried looking for examples/explanations for similar problems in my text to no avail so pardon me for simply asking for general guidance on how to approach these problems.

Comment: How does this not apply to my tags? This is literally a part of a differential equations course and involves initial values. If my question is so irrelevant, and you can't (or won't) offer the simplest bit of help, why did you click on it, let alone take the time to leave two comments criticizing it? @Did

Comment: Let us stick to the non-pure-rant part of your comments: "How does this not apply to my tags?" The tag (differential-equations) is irrelevant because there is no differential equation in the question and none involved in its solutions. The tag (initial-value-problems) is irrelevant because there is no initial value problem in the question and none involved in its solutions. Please read the descriptions of these tags. All in all, your comments sound like some pure noise emitted with the goal of hiding the fact that your posts regularly lack any context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try a few terms to see the pattern. Then apply inductively.

$$y_1=-0.5y_0+6 = (-1)^1(0.5)^1(y_0-4)+4$$

$$y_2=-0.5y_1+6 = -0.5(-0.5y_0+6)+6 = (-1)^2(0.5)^2(y_0-4)+4$$

$$\vdots$$

$$y_n = -0.5(y_{n-1})+6 =  -0.5[(-1)^{n-1}(0.5)^{n-1}(y_0-4)+4] + 6 =  (-1)^{n}(0.5)^{n}(y_0-4) + 4$$

Where the last $+4$ comes from distributing the $-0.5$ to the $+4$ and adding it to $6$.